# scheduled executor accuracy

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I am having a problem with the ScheduledExecutorService in java (I didn't face this problem a couple of days back is what makes it strange for me). Please find the code below and the console output. The delay between executing the task repeatedly is 1 ms so I should ideally be reaching the count of 1000 every second (give or take a few milliseconds) but this is just not happening. Please help..

CODE:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class SchedulerTest {

     private static final ScheduledExecutorService executor =       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
     static DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

     private static class TestRunnable1 implements Runnable{
         private int count=0;

         @Override
          public void run() {
           count++;
           if(count1 % 1000==0){
              System.out.println(count1+"  "+df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
            }
     
         }
    }

  
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Runnable localService = new TestRunnable1();
      try{
           executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(localService, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
         }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
 }
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
1000 13-Mar-2013 14:43:54.477
2000 13-Mar-2013 14:44:10.296
3000 13-Mar-2013 14:44:26.381
4000 13-Mar-2013 14:44:42.621
5000 13-Mar-2013 14:44:55.907
6000 13-Mar-2013 14:44:58.516
7000 13-Mar-2013 14:45:05.896
8000 13-Mar-2013 14:45:10.292
9000 13-Mar-2013 14:45:15.129
10000 13-Mar-2013 14:45:18.187
```

Comment: That is not the code you are running (does not compile). Fixing the compilation I get about 1.2-1.3 seconds between each print, which seems reasonable if the time include housekeeping within the scheduler. If I change to scheduleAtFixedRate I get the prints to be spot on the second (at least when measured on the millisecond level).

Comment: Thank you!! your suggestion worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate` rather than `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay`.

If you schedule with a fixed delay, then 1 ms must elapse between the time that the last execution completed and the time that the next execution begins.  So the wall-clock time that it takes to complete 1000 iterations will be, at a minimum, 1 second *plus* the execution time of the thousand iterations.

Comment: Thanks that worked!! I should have read the API thoroughly  :)